# CSS Grid inside Max-width Container

Tags: html, css, grid

I have a parent section div with a max-width of 1760px.

I can put a carousel directly inside a section container and it will take the width of the viewport up to 1760px i have set, works as expected. *carousel will try to fill 100% of space given.

However, the issue is that i want to put the content inside a 2 col grid, inside container, but the first part of the grid has the carousel that takes the max-width of parent section, rather than stopping at width of page. So, rather than take 2fr of the viewport (map takes 1fr), it fills whole of 1760px so the screen overflows.

Style wise, The best example i can find online to show what i mean is Airbnb listing, it has 2 cols, 1 with listing and 1 with map. This is pretty much what i am trying to replicate.

Here is the carousel directly in section (pretty simple and works as explained above). If i put the carousel inside this it doesn't overflow page.

```
<section>
    <div>Carousel</div>
</section>

section{
     max-width: 1760px;
     padding: 50px 40px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Once i add it inside a grid it ignores the viewport size and simply fills max-width of section (1760px) and overflows viewport width.

```
<section>
    <div class="grid">
        <div>Carousel</div>
        <div>Map</div>
    </div>
</section>

.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

It actually works using grid-template-columns: 60% 40%; instead of 2fr 1fr, and removing margin: 0 auto. But this means i cannot use gap (which is fine).

To summerize, how can i use fr sizing and make sure it takes notice of viewport size, and not just take up the max-width value by default.

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear, if you post the working code with reproducible output, will be helpful to identify the problem

Comment: Thank you, I have edited to hopefully make it clearer now. Essentially, using 2fr 1fr rather than % causes the max-width of section to be filled regardless of screen size.

Comment: I also mentioned if you add code which will reproduce the issue, will make us understand the problem in a better way

Comment: The code is above, its as simple as that, theres not much more to it. If i added anything extra id just be bloating the question for no real benefit.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Spirconi/pen/JjKVYJW - this pen shows similar issue with image rather than carousel. As you can see it takes max-width rather than viewport, and shrinks 2nd grid column as well.

Comment: okay cool, will take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

I went through your pen and made some changes and it gave the result as you wanted it to be, no overflowing of the image.

If you do following changes, it will work for you too:

1. These are not mandatory, if you wish you can do the changes or else you can keep as it is.

- Remove the `max-width: 1760px` from section style.
- Add `max-width: 1760px` to the grid element, since you are providing the max-width to the grid, the parent section will also have this max-width, since grid is the child element.

2. Now make sure you are applying the `width: 100%` to the images (This is mandatory). Like this:

```css
.listing > img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

OR, if you have nested elements inside `.listing` element and `img` tag is not the immediate child of the `.listing` element, then you can go with this way:

```css
.listing img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

So every `img` tag which is direct or indirect descendent of `.listing` element will have width 100%

Here's the working piece of example:
https://codepen.io/prathameshkoshti/pen/KKMYoWY?editors=0100

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but i know I can add 100% to the image, the issue is it does not work for carousel, so i need a solution without targeting the internal elements of the grid. I think i will just have to go with % for now and re address when i can show the issue better on here.

Comment: I don't think there will be any other option than this one, because when you load an image, the image will take up its actual size only if you don't specify the width/height, but if you do specify then image will try to fit into the parent div (key to the responsive images).